# auto expand hyperlinks in emails in Outlook with actual URL (prevent phishing)

Tags: css, outlook, hyperlink, phishing

For emails to Office365 accounts as viewed in a modern Outlook, is there a way to auto expand hyperlinks with the actual underlying URL. This way, users can immediately see where the URL is actually taking them, as opposed to having to trust the displayed hyperlink text or having to remember to hover over the hyperlink.

For example, auto convert [https://harmless.com](https://www.malicious.com) into `https://harmless.com` [http://malicious.com]

This appears like a very good middle ground between disabling all hyperlinks which a hassle for users, and having to rely on Microsoft's filtering capability in something like Safe Link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to customize Outlook, but what you're wanting can be done by styling the hyperlink (for example, `visibility:hidden`), and displaying the URL of the hyperlink in a pseudo element using `attr(href)`.

```css
a{visibility:hidden}

a::after{
 content: attr(href)"";
 visibility:visible
}
```

```html
<a href="maliciouslink.com">harmless link</a>
```